# keep track of the previous i in for loop java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to get the current `i` value and the previous `i` value in a for loop. Is that possible?

```
public void mousePressed() {  
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    if (mouseX > boxes[i].x) {
      boxes.[i].openIt();
    }
  }
}
```

If I print `i` I will get the current value of `i`

```
System.out.println(i);
```

How do I print the previous value of `i`? I don't want to use `i-1` because I am using random numbers in my project.

Comment: Maybe have another variable called `previousI`, and write `previousI = i;` as the last line of your loop.

Comment: You should probably post code that corresponds to your *actual* problem, rather than this code which is *not* your problem ;)

Comment: Using random numbers? In what way do you iterate over these random numbers? If the random numbers don't have an index then you're most likely in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i= -1;
int prev= -1;
boolean cond = true;
public void mousePressed() {  
    while(cond){
        i=myPositiveRNG.nextInt();//assuming positive numbers, 'cause it's an array index.
        if(prev>-1){
            System.out.println(prev);
        }
        if (mouseX > boxes[i].x){
            boxes.[i].openIt();
        }
        prev = i;
        cond=isItTimeToGo();
}
```

Tailor this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the most straightforward way:

```
public void mousePressed() {
  int lastProcessedI = -1;//Or some reasonable default value
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println("On iteration " + i + " having completed " + lastProcessedI);
    if (mouseX > boxes[i].x) {
      boxes.[i].openIt();
    }
    lastProcessedI = i;//mark i as having been processed.
  }
}
```

Note that `lastProcessedI` should be declared prior to your for loop, because otherwise it will go out of scope when the loop iterates. By declaring it ahead of your for loop, it stays in the containing scope of the `mousePressed` method.

If you need to maintain more history this is also easy to implement:

```
public void mousePressed() {
  List<Integer> processHistory = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    System.out.println("On iteration " + i + " having completed " + processHistory.get(processHistory.size() - 1));
    if (mouseX > boxes[i].x) {
      boxes.[i].openIt();
    }
    processHistory.add(i);//store i as having been processed.
  }

  //here you can get any previously processed i
  processHistory.get(processHistory.size() - 2);//I selected 2 arbitrarily, but it will provide the second-to-last i processed.
}
```

Comment: When loop exits lastProcessedI will have value of the last i. If you add lastProcessedII that will hold value of lastProcessedI you'll have  in lastProcessedII previous value of i when loop exits.

Comment: You might want to use an `Integer` instead of an `int` for `lastProcessedI`, and use `null` as its initial value; just in case `-1` is a valid value for `i` (OP has said that `i` is somehow random).

Comment: @user987339 I'm afraid your comment does not make grammatical sense, so it is unclear what you're trying to convey. `lastProcessedI` will have the last value of `i` when the for loop exists; no need to add nor have an additional variable.

Comment: @DavidWallace That is reasonable, except that if he is really outputting that value it probably shouldn't be `null`; or, at the least, it will require more code to properly handle that case.

Comment: I don't want to use -1 as I created if inside the loop in my project so that when I run it and click it gives me a value from 1-10 depending on where I click. Then when I click again I have another value. I am trying to get the first value and the second value. This will defer every time. For example I could get 2 and 8, or 1 and 10 or any 2 values form 1-10. I want to print the first and the second value.

Comment: Wait a minute... you sound like you're describing a VERY DIFFERENT specification. Are you saying that one value of `i` in the for loop (determined by `openIt()`?) should be preserved for the next mouse click? (Which is to say, a subsequent entering into the mouseClick function?)

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford As you "said lastProcessedI will have the last value of i when the for loop exists". But the question is "How do I print the previous value of i?"

Comment: @user987339 The question depends on which point in time you want to print the previous value of `i`. In the code as-provided, the print statement is BEFORE the update of `lastProcessedI`, therefore will print the previous `i`. (I encourage you to test this yourself.) However, I've provided a general solution for storing and retrieving the entire history of processing.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford There is no print inside loop, so I suppose that print is after the loop. So put prints for i and lastProcessedI after the loop and test your code. This goes for the first solution you proposed. Second solution will work as should.

Comment: @user987339 Line 4 is a print statement.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford In the question code - there is no print inside loop, so I suppose that print is after the loop. So put prints for i and lastProcessedI after the loop in your first solution and test your code. Are i and lastProcessedI the same? In question code he expects different values after loop.

Comment: @user987339 Then use the general form I provided; this is a silly point to be objecting to, as the OP did not say there was a requirement as to when the variable is printed (and therefore you're assuming facts not in evidence), and the second-to-last value is printed in the original solution I provided.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford As I already said: "Second solution will work as should".